# A specific effect in css and bootstrap

Tags: text, background, vertical-alignment

I am new to bootstrap and made some stuff.

but there is a specific effect of highlight a text i can't reach. i made it wrong many times - like the BG was offset or the line had no spacing and many more problems.

Can you please explain me how to do this ?

T[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3QxF.jpg)hank !

edit:
Thae image is photoshop, how the final result should look

Comment: What's the effect? The border at the left side of the link or the background color on hover?

Comment: both of them. the effect should be the highlighted background and the thin line to the right (with the spacing). i can't get it right : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could work with a border and padding like in the following demo and this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/f5hwaq57/).

For the unhovered link I've added a transparent border to avoid jumping on hover. You could probably also do this with margin/padding.

```css
.styled-link {
  color: #5F6065;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 15px;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.styled-link:hover {
  color: gray;
  background-color: #D1E7FE;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" class="styled-link">Highlighted link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you this is exacly what i wanted. i will also look at it and learn from it for future tasks !

awesome !!

Comment: Is there a way to make the line seperate from the background a few pixels like in the image i uploaded? 

Thanks

Comment: With `content-box` for background-clip like in this [css-trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/). You could get it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/f5hwaq57/1/)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. is it possible to have the hightlighted background big (same size as the line) while the text small ? if i down the text size the hightlight size get smaller as well

Comment: You're welcome. `display: inline-block;` should help here. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/f5hwaq57/2/).

Comment: Thanks. only thing i still can't make is having the highlighted bg to be same fixed size, which should always be wider then the text and pass it to the right and a little to the left, and still not touching the line (link the image). something like 250 pixels.

how can i do this ? 
awesome place

Comment: With `text-indent` you can move the text a bit to the right and with a width you can adjust the size. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/f5hwaq57/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

With the use of pseudo elements we can make a ::before element appear on hover

https://jsfiddle.net/jfe1uf50/

```
.cool-link {
  color:red;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 15px;
  &:hover {
    color:blue;
    &::before {
     position:absolute;
     left:-5px;
     content:"";
     height:100%;
     width:3px;
     background-color:blue;
    }
  }
}
<a href="/" class="cool-link">Hello World!</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, only the background is missing